# Undefined Method Error when creating delayed_job workers with script/delay_job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid, delayed-job

Having a bit of a problem running multiple workers.

When creating workers with `rake jobs:work` jobs run without and problem, even when invoking it multiple times, but when creating workers with `ruby script/delayed_job -n 5 start all` jobs fail with undefined method on `Syck::DomainType`.

I've searched quite a bit, but can't seem to find the solution for this. I am running DelayedJob on the Mongoid backend. Gem versions:

- rake 0.9.2
- rails 3.0.6
- delayedjob 2.1.4
- delayedjob_mongoid 1.0.2

Has anyone experienced a similar error/have a solution? Or short of that some information on why/how workers are being created differently depending on which way they are invoked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem was derived from bundler >= 1.0.10 loading up psych and overwriting some of sycks functionality if libyaml is present.  I was able to remove the libyaml install from my system, something that I know won't be possible for everyone.  Tough to track down, hopefully this post will help someone else

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. I could reproduce it by loading the job in the console and trying to unserialize it:

```
$ rails console production
> j = Delayed::Job.last
> YAML.load(j.handler)
```

On my production environment, I got a Syck::DomainType object whereas in development it just unserialized my object (the data stored in db is the same in both case).

Long story short, I realized that I had ruby 1.9.1 instead of 1.9.2 on my server. Switching to an rvm managed environment with ruby-1.9.2p290 solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `ruby script/delayed_job -n 5 start all` doesn't invoke `Bundler.setup` and that's why it's different from other ways of launching workers? (Just a guess)

You may be able to fix the `Syck::DomainType` error by putting this at the top of `config/application.rb`

```
require 'yaml'
YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'syck'
# [...]
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)
```

Thanks to this answer: [rails error, couldn't parse YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980877/rails-error-couldnt-parse-yaml)

Comment: No change in behavior.  Adding those.  Previously had set syck to my yamler so only addition was the require 'yaml' line.  Same error though

Answer (score 0):

Run it with:

```
bundle exec ./script/delayed_job -n 5 start
```