# Delayed Job failing in Production environment on Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I am using delayed_job gem for sending emails in my rails app.
delayed_job was working well but from last 5 days, it is not working and throwing following error in delayed_job.log file.

```
2011-10-09T01:53:04+0530: [Worker(delayed_job host:backupserver pid:23953)] Syck::DomainType#private_group_join_request failed with NoMethodError: undefined method private_group_join_request' for # - 11 failed attempts
2011-10-09T01:53:04+0530: [Worker(delayed_job host:backupserver pid:23953)] 1 jobs processed at 1.4503 j/s, 1 failed ...
2011-10-09T01:54:40+0530: [Worker(delayed_job host:backupserver pid:23953)] Syck::DomainType#contact_us_email failed with NoMethodError: undefined method contact_us_email for # - 11 failed attempts
2011-10-09T01:54:40+0530: [Worker(delayed_job host:backupserver pid:23953)] 1 jobs processed at 4.3384 j/s, 1 failed ...
```

Following is one of the example how I am calling delayed job for sending email.

```
UserMailer.delay(:run_at => 10.seconds.from_now).contact_us_email(self)
```

I am starting delayed job with

```
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start
```

It is working correctly in development as well as production environment on my local machine.

Environment Which I am using in Rails App.

- Rails 3.0.8
- Ruby 1.9.2 in Linux(Ubuntu)
- rake 0.9.2
- delayed_job 2.1.4

This is same as 
[Undefined Method Error when creating delayed_job workers with script/delay_job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766431/undefined-method-error-when-creating-delayed-job-workers-with-script-delay-job)

But solution is not working for me.

Comment: The "undefined method foo for #" is odd -- usually that sort of things is saying undefined method foo for nil, and then the problem is that the function is being called on a nil object. Do you have any idea what the "#" is referring to in your environment?

Comment: I found the reason why the delayed job was failing. As per given in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766431/undefined-method-error-when-creating-delayed-job-workers-with-script-delay-job  the reason for failing was libyaml package. Package was installed on Server but is not installed on my local machine. Now I have installed the same package on my local machine, and it is giving me the same error. This error is coming at the time of deserialisation of data from database.

Comment: Kaplesh: you might as well answer your own question so it is shown as answered, and other people would benefit from seeing how you fixed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out. It was due to package "**libyaml**" package, which was not present on my local system but was installed on server.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you didn't stop and start your delayed_job worker when you deployed some new code? If a worker that was running before the deploy is trying to run new methods, it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that YAML (or Syck) running in the worker process doesn't know about the method in question?  Take a look at:

https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/wiki/Common-problems#wiki-jobs_are_silently_removed_from_the_database

... the relevant part is:

> One common cause of deserialization errors is that the YAML references
>   a class not known to the worker. If this is the case, you can add
>
> ```
> # file: config/initializers/custom.rb
> require 'my_custom_class'
> ```
>
> which will force my_custom_class to be loaded when the worker starts.

Comment: What would this look like?  'required "User"'?  And, that would load the User model?

Comment: @hellion: close.  Try `require 'user'` -- of course, this depends upon your path being set up properly and such.  I don't know enough about your environment to give you a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had to restart my unicorns on the production server, by hand because for some reason cap deploy was not doing it for me.

So what I had to do was:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/unicorn_myapp stop
sudo /etc/init.d/unicorn_myapp start
```

But unicorn wasn't able to start, so I had to

```
sudo rm /tmp/unicorn.my_app.sock
```

And

```
sudo /etc/init.d/unicorn_myapp start
```