# "undefined method" error when running delayed_jobs in multiple queues with ./script/delayed_job -n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, syck

Having a problem with running delayed jobs in multiple queues.
I had the same problem at the beginning when I ran all in one queue with

```
rake jobs:work
```

But solved it by running

```
bundle exec rake jobs:work.
```

Now for running different queues, I'm using:
    ./script/delayed_job -n 2 start

and back to start with the error.
The error is:

> "Syck::DomainType#{method_name} failed with NoMethodError: undefined method `{method_name}' for #

I have tried to resolve it by adding the code to application.rb as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766431/undefined-method-error-when-creating-delayed-job-workers-with-script-delay-job):

```
require 'yaml'
YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'syck'
# [...]
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)
```

But it didn't help.
I'm using:
Rails 3.0.9
Ruby 1.9.2 p290

Thanks :)
Moozly.

Comment: You probably running wrong version of rake. Paste your script content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, try

```
bundle exec ./script/delayed_job -n 2 start
```

;)

Comment: lol :), I somehow thought it didn't work with it, but it does :)