# YAML DB won't run due to evaluating nil.each

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So this problem is occurring for me on both RHEL5 and OSX Lion. Both environments are running 1.9.2-p290 ruby installed with RVM.

When I run the following command I get the following problem:

```
[master][~/Sites/boss-mocha] bundle exec rake db:data:load --trace
** Invoke db:data:load (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:data:load
rake aborted!
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.each
/Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/yaml_db-0.2.1/lib/serialization_helper.rb:85:in `load_records'
/Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/yaml_db-0.2.1/lib/serialization_helper.rb:74:in `load_table'
/Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/yaml_db-0.2.1/lib/yaml_db.rb:63:in `block (2 levels) in load_documents'
/Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/yaml_db-0.2.1/lib/yaml_db.rb:61:in `each'
/Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/yaml_db-0.2.1/lib/yaml_db.rb:61:in `block in load_documents'
/Users/pma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/deprecated.rb:30:in `each'
/Users/pma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/deprecated.rb:30:in `load_documents'
/Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/yaml_db-0.2.1/lib/yaml_db.rb:60:in `load_documents'
/Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/yaml_db-0.2.1/lib/serialization_helper.rb:57:in `block in load'
/Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:139:in `transaction'
/Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/yaml_db-0.2.1/lib/serialization_helper.rb:56:in `load'
/Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/yaml_db-0.2.1/lib/serialization_helper.rb:31:in `load'
/Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/yaml_db-0.2.1/lib/tasks/yaml_db_tasks.rake:35:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/pma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `invoke_task'
/Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `each'
/Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `block in top_level'
/Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:84:in `top_level'
/Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:62:in `block in run'
/Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:data:load
```

Comment: having this problem too.

Answer (score 0):

The YAML being produced by rake db:data:dump appears mal-formed, with spurious "---"s between the "records" list and the actual records.

Removing the inappropriate "---" allows the data to load. I haven't created a pull request for the fix yet, but after tracking it down I noticed someone else reported it as an issue on github:

https://github.com/ludicast/yaml_db/issues/17

In addition, changing the YAML engine as in the link below produces correct output, eliminating the need for editing the file manually (or fixing yaml_db).

[rails error, couldn't parse YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980877/rails-error-couldnt-parse-yaml)