# Rails 3 - psych.rb - couldn't parse YAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backgroundrb

While integrating backgroundrb-rails3 I get the following error,

```
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:148:in `parse': couldn't parse YAML at line 8 column 22 (Psych::SyntaxError)
from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:148:in `parse_stream'
from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:119:in `parse'
from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:106:in `load'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/backgroundrb-rails3-1.1.6/lib/backgroundrb/bdrb_config.rb:27:in `read_config'
from ~/workspace/artbee/Trunk/script/load_worker_env.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/packet-0.1.15/bin/packet_worker_runner:25:in `require'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/packet-0.1.15/bin/packet_worker_runner:25:in `initialize'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/packet-0.1.15/bin/packet_worker_runner:47:in `new'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/packet-0.1.15/bin/packet_worker_runner:47:in `<top (required)>'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/packet_worker_runner:19:in `load'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/packet_worker_runner:19:in `<main>'
```

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980877/rails-error-couldnt-parse-yaml) in stack overflow and the accepted answer works for me.

I don't want to use Syck, how can i fix it with Psych? Is there any difference in yml format for both? As the backtrace is not pointing to any yaml file, how can i debug more?

Any help is highly appreciated...

Comment: What is the YAML in question?

Comment: @jordan,I am afraid I don't know which Yaml file the error is pointing to. What I have is the backtrace, that I posted above.

Comment: Your app should have a `config/backgroundrb.yml` file that you could post? Otherwise, it may be the default one (in which case I don't see any issues with the default one at https://github.com/mtylty/backgroundrb-rails3/blob/master/config/backgroundrb.yml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it looks like Psych can't parse this specific line from the default configuration:

```
:trigger_args: */5 * * * * * *
```

Wrapping the conditions in quotes should fix it:

```
:trigger_args: "*/5 * * * * * *"
```

You can copy the default config into your `config` folder and make this change there. Here is the exact file to use: https://raw.github.com/mtylty/backgroundrb-rails3/master/config/backgroundrb.yml