# Job handler serialization incorrect when running delayed_job in production with Thin or Unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, delayed-job, thin, unicorn

I recently brought delayed_job into my Rails 3.1.3 app. In development 
everything is fine. I even staged my DJ release on the same VPS as my 
production app using the same production application server (Thin), 
and everything was fine. Once I released to production, however, all 
hell broke loose: none of the jobs were entered into the jobs table 
correctly, and I started seeing the following in the logs for all 
processed jobs:

```
2012-02-18T14:41:51-0600: [Worker(delayed_job host:hope pid:12965)] 
NilClass# completed after 0.0151 
2012-02-18T14:41:51-0600: [Worker(delayed_job host:hope pid:12965)] 1 
jobs processed at 15.9666 j/s, 0 failed ...
```

NilClass and no method name? Certainly not correct. So I looked at the 
serialized handler on the job in the DB and saw:

```
"--- !ruby/object:Delayed::PerformableMethod\nattributes:\n  id: 13\n 
event_id: 26\n  name: memememe\n  api_key: !!null \n"
```

No indication of a class or method name. And when I load the YAML into 
an object and call #object on the resulting PerformableMethod I get 
nil. For kicks I then fired up the console on the broken production 
app and delayed the same job. This time the handler looked like:

```
"--- !ruby/object:Delayed::PerformableMethod\nobject: !ruby/ 
ActiveRecord:Domain\n  attributes:\n    id: 13\n    event_id: 26\n 
name: memememe\n    api_key: !!null \nmethod_name: :create_a\nargs: [] 
\n"
```

And sure enough, that job runs fine. Puzzled, I then recalled reading 
something about DJ not playing nice with Thin. So, I tried Unicorn and 
was sad to see the same result. Hours of research later and I think 
this has something to do with how the app server is loading the YAML 
libraries Psych and Syck and DJ's interaction with them. I cannot, 
however, pin down exactly what is wrong.

Note that I'm running delayed_job 3.0.1 official, but have tried upgrading to 
the master branch and have even tried downgrading to 2.1.4. 
Here are some notable differences between my stage and production 
setups:

- In stage I run 1 Thin server on a TCP port -- no web proxy in front
- In production I run 2+ Thin servers and proxy to them with Nginx. 
  They talk over a UNIX socket
- When I tried unicorn it was 1 app server proxied to by Nginx over a 
  UNIX socket

Could the web proxying/Nginx have something to do with it? Please, any insight is greatly appreciated. I've spent a lot of time 
integrating delayed_job and would hate to have to shelve the work or, worse, 
toss it. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by not using #delay. Instead I replaced all of my "model.delay.method" code with custom jobs. Doing so works like a charm, and is ultimately more flexible. This fix works fine with Thin. I haven't tested with Unicorn.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into a similar problem with rails 3.0.10 and dj 2.1.4, it's most certainly a different yaml library being loaded when running from console vs from the app server; thin, unicorn, nginx. I'll share any solution I come up with

Ok so removing these lines from config/boot.rb fixed this issue for me.

```
require 'yaml'
YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'syck'
```

This had been placed there to fix an YAML parsing error, forcing YAML to use 'syck'. Removing this required me to fix the underlying issues with the .yml files. More on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980877/rails-error-couldnt-parse-yaml)

Now my delayed job record handlers match between those created via the server (unicorn in my case) and the console. Both my server and delayed job workers are kicked off within bundler

Unicorn

```
cd #{rails_root} && bundle exec unicorn_rails -c #{rails_root}/config/unicorn.rb -E #{rails_env} -D"
```

DJ

```
export LANG=en_US.utf8; export GEM_HOME=/data/reception/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1; cd #{rail
```

s_root}; /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 /data/reception/current/script/delayed_job start staging

Comment: Thanks Mark. I'm still struggling with this.I'm currently trying to run my app in Nginx/(mod) Passenger. I'll report back when I know whether or not that app server works better.