# How do I fix a "NilClass# completed after" error while using delayed_job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, delayed-job

I am using collectiveidea/delayed_job to delay the makesandwich method in my Lesson model. It works fine in development but gives the error below when run in production:

```
Worker(host:b75643e6-bc2b-4f9f-97ff-b31aa3c50b0f pid:2)] Starting job worker
[Worker(host:b75643e6-bc2b-4f9f-97ff-b31aa3c50b0f pid:2)] NilClass# completed after 0.0095
[Worker(host:b75643e6-bc2b-4f9f-97ff-b31aa3c50b0f pid:2)] 1 jobs processed at 5.5022 j/s, 0 failed ...
```

How can I fix this problem?

Here is my model and method:

```
#encoding: utf-8

class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :content, :title, :parsed_content, :html_content, :user_id

    serialize :parsed_content, Array
    serialize :html_content, Array
    serialize :pinyin_content, Array
    serialize :defined_content, Array
    serialize :literal_content, Array

    validates :title, :presence => true
    validates :content, :presence => true

    belongs_to :user

    #before_update do |lesson|
    #   lesson.makesandwich
    #end

    after_create do |lesson|
        lesson.makesandwich
    end

    def makesandwich

        require 'rmmseg'
                                                        #require 'to_lang'
        require 'bing_translator'
        require 'ruby-pinyin'

        self.parsed_content = []

        RMMSeg::Dictionary.load_dictionaries

        content             = self.content
        paragraphs          = content.split(/\r\n\r\n/) #convert to array of paragraphs
        self.parsed_content = paragraphs
        paragraphs.each_with_index do |text, ti|

            text = text.gsub("。", "^^.")
            text = text.gsub("？", "~~?")
            text = text.gsub("！", "||!")
            text = text.gsub(":", "：")  #fix missing colons

            text = text.split(/[.?!]/u) #convert to an array
            text.each do |s|
                s.gsub!("^^", "。")
                s.gsub!("~~", "？")
                s.gsub!("||", "！")
                #s.gsub!("———————————",":")
            end

            text.each_with_index do |val, index|
                algor     = RMMSeg::Algorithm.new(text[index])
                splittext = []
                loop do
                    tok = algor.next_token
                    break if tok.nil?
                    tex = tok.text.force_encoding('UTF-8')
                    splittext << tex
                    text[index] = splittext
                end
                paragraphs[ti] = text
            end
        end
        bing                 = BingTranslator.new('8bacb905-c59b-4363-bbf5-89ef2c32c26e', 'g82QvinzO7GhmP7qJQpfxTMXzClSGX3yiPcsedFDXYQ=')
        self.parsed_content  = paragraphs
        textarray            = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(paragraphs))
        self.defined_content = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(paragraphs))
        self.literal_content = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(paragraphs))
        self.pinyin_content  = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(paragraphs))
        textarray.each_with_index do |paragraph, pi|
            paragraph.each_with_index do |sentence, si|
                sentence.each_with_index do |word, wi|
                    if DictionaryEntry.find_by_simplified(word) != nil
                        self.defined_content[pi][si][wi] = DictionaryEntry.find_by_simplified(word).definition
                        #self.literal_content is down below
                        self.pinyin_content[pi][si][wi]  = DictionaryEntry.find_by_simplified(word).pinyin
                    else
                        self.defined_content[pi][si][wi] = bing.translate(word, :from => 'zh-CHS', :to => 'en')
                        #self.defined_content[pi][si][wi] = word
                        #self.literal_content is down below
                        if PinYin.of_string(word, true).length > 1 #for punctuation
                            self.pinyin_content[pi][si][wi] = PinYin.of_string(word, true).join(" ").downcase
                        else
                            self.pinyin_content[pi][si][wi] = word
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
        end

        #Literal
        literalarray = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(paragraphs))
        literalarray.each_with_index do |paragraph, pi|
            paragraph.each_with_index do |sentence, si| #iterate array of sentence
                literalarray[pi][si] = []
                sentence.each_with_index do |word, wi| #iterate sentence's array of words
                    entrytobesliced = DictionaryEntry.find_by_simplified(word)
                    slicedentry     = []

                    if entrytobesliced == nil
                        if word.length > 1 && word !~ /\w/ #/^\s*\w\d+\s*$/ #number regex  #for cases where there is no DictionaryEntry
                            split     = []
                            wordarray = word.split("").each_with_index() do |ws, wsi|
                                split << [DictionaryEntry.find_by_simplified(ws).definition]
                            end
                            literalarray[pi][si] << split
                        else
                            literalarray[pi][si] << [word] #in case none of the above work
                        end
                    else
                        entrytobesliced.simplified.each_char do |w|
                            singlechar = DictionaryEntry.find_by_simplified(w)
                            slicedentry << singlechar.definition.split("\", \"")
                        end
                        literalarray[pi][si] << slicedentry
                    end
                    self.literal_content = literalarray #slicedentry #literalarray
                end
            end
        end
        self.save
    end
    handle_asynchronously :makesandwich
end
```

Here is what the job looked like in the database:

```
irb(main):012:0> job
=> #<Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job id: 5, priority: 0, attempts: 0, handler: "--- !ruby/object:Delayed::PerformableMethod\nattribu...", last_error: nil, run_at: "2013-01-13 19:42:38", locked_at: nil, failed_at: nil, locked_by: nil, queue: nil, created_at: "2013-01-13 19:42:38", updated_at: "2013-01-13 19:42:38">
```

Here is the handler:

```
irb(main):011:0> job.handler
=> "--- !ruby/object:Delayed::PerformableMethod\nattributes:\n  id: 14\n  title: test\n  content: ! \"1最初，上帝创造了天地。\\r\\n\\r\\n2大地混沌苍茫，深渊的表面一片黑暗。上帝发出的动力运行在水面上。\\r\\n\\r\\n3上帝说：“要有光。”光就出现了。4上帝看光是好的。上帝把光暗分开了。5上帝称光为“昼”，称暗为“夜”。过了晚上，到了早晨，是第一日。\\r\\n\\r\\n6上帝说：“水和水之间要有天空，把水上下分开。”7于是上帝造出天空把水分开，天空以下有水，天空以上也有水。事就这样成了。8上帝称天空为“天”。过了晚上，到了早晨，是第二日。\\r\\n\\r\\n9上帝说：“天下的水要聚在一处，让陆地露出来。”事就这样成了。10上帝称陆地为“地”，称聚起来的水为“海”。上帝看这是好的。11上帝说：“地要长出青草和结种子的植物，又要长出结果子的树木，各按其类；果子里要有种子，在地上生长。”事就这样成了。12地上长出青草和结种子的植物，各按其类；又长出结果子的树木，果子里都有种子，各按其类。上帝看这是好的。13过了晚上，到了早晨，是第三日。\\r\\n\\r\\n14上帝说：“天空要有光源，可以分昼夜，做记号，定季节、日子、年月。15光源要在天空普照大地。”事就这样成了。16上帝造出两大光源，大的管昼，小的管夜，又造星星。17上帝把光源放在天空，普照大地，18支配昼夜，分开光暗。上帝看这是好的。19过了晚上，到了早晨，是第四日。\\r\\n\\r\\n20上帝说：“水里要涌现成群的活物，地上要有飞禽在天空飞翔。”21于是上帝创造巨大的海兽，使水里涌现各样游动的活物，各按其类；又创造各种有翅膀的飞禽，各按其类。上帝看这是好的。22上帝赐福给这些活物说：“要繁衍增多，充满海洋；飞禽也要在地上增多。”23过了晚上，到了早晨，是第五日。\\r\\n\\r\\n24上帝说：“地要生出活物来，各按其类，就是牲畜、爬行的动物、地上的走兽，各按其类。”事就这样成了。25上帝造出地上的走兽，各按其类；牲畜，各按其类；地上各样爬行的动物，各按其类。上帝看这是好的。\\r\\n\\r\\n26上帝说：“我们要照我们的形像、按我们的样式造人，让他们管理海里的鱼、天上的飞禽、地上的牲畜，以及全地和地上各样爬行的动物。”27于是上帝照自己的形像创造人，就是照上帝的形像把人创造出来。上帝创造了男人和女人。28上帝赐福给他们，对他们说：“要繁衍增多，遍满地面，开拓大地，也要管理海里的鱼、天上的飞禽和地上各样爬行的活物。”\\r\\n\\r\\n29上帝说：“全地上各样结种子的植物和各样结种子的果树，我都赐给你们做食物。30至于地上各样的走兽、天上各样的飞禽、地上各样有生命的爬行动物，我把一切青菜绿叶都赐给它们吃。”事就这样成了。\\r\\n\\r\\n31上帝看他所造的一切，都非常好。过了晚上，到了早晨，是第六日。\"\n  created_at: 2013-01-13 19:42:38.696201148 Z\n  updated_at: 2013-01-13 19:42:38.696201148 Z\n  parsed_content: []\n  html_content: []\n  literal_content: []\n  pinyin_content: []\n  defined_content: []\n  user_id: 1\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely getting picked up by the background job before it's actually committed to the database. Try changing your callback to `after_commit`:

```
after_commit do |lesson|
  lesson.makesandwich
end
```

You can also just send it a symbol for the method you want to execute:

```
after_commit :makesandwich
```

Here are a few resources describing why you should use after_commit instead of after_save/ceate:

- http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/695-use-after_commit
- http://alindeman.github.com/2011/10/02/after-save-and-background-jobs.html

Comment: I tried what you suggested and it still didn't work. I don't understand why it would work in development, but not on heroku.

Comment: The local database is likely faster in development since it doesn't have any load on it. Here are some resources on it http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/695-use-after_commit and http://alindeman.github.com/2011/10/02/after-save-and-background-jobs.html

Comment: Thanks but changing it to after_commit didn't help. Do you have any other ideas I should explore?

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is related to:

[Job handler serialization incorrect when running delayed_job in production with Thin or Unicorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386491/job-handler-serialization-incorrect-when-running-delayed-job-in-production-with)

I'm having the same problem - I'm guessing your gems are not locked down well enough ( I think that's my issue too )

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by setting up my app to use Unicorn on Heroku.  (I assume you are using Heroku...at least that's what the sample logs look like.)  I followed the "Web Server" part of [this Heroku guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails4-getting-started#webserver).

Next (and I think this is the critical part) I added `worker:  bundle exec rake jobs:work` to the `Procfile` as specified in [Delayed Job (DJ)](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/delayed-job#setting-up-delayed-job) and delayed_job started working as expected with no other code changes.