# Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.2 serialized hash cannot be deserialized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, yaml, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-1.9.3

Basically, I upgraded a 1.8.7@rails2 app to 1.9.3@rails3.2

When trying to use `.each_pair` on a serialized hash, I end up getting

```
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
       @measure.coefficients.each_pair |key, value|
```

When trying to access the rails console to load up that `measure.coefficients`, it gives me a string.  Which if I try running `YAML.load(serialized_string)` in either "psych' or 'syck' as instructed by the following answer
[rails error, couldn't parse YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980877/rails-error-couldnt-parse-yaml)

I end up getting

```
ArgumentError: syntax error on line 21, col 5: `'
from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:135:in `load'
```

Similar result when using 'psych' engine.  Anyclue?

Here is a sample of the hash in string format:

```
"--- !map:HashWithIndifferentAccess \n\"1092\": \"\"\n\"869\": \"\"\n\"1039\": \"\"\n\"2492\": \"\"\n\"1389\": \"\"\n\"1200\": \"\"\n\"600\": \"\"\n\"1928\": \"\"\n\"1767\": \"\"\n\"1498\": \"\"\n\"899\": \"\"\n\"711\": \"\"\n\"1124\": \"\"\n\"1312\": \"\"\n\"1500\": \"\"\n\"900\": \"\"\n\"1152\": \"\"\n\"1232\": \"\"\n\"1340\": \"\"\n\"1420\": \"\"\n\"123"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you actually print the value, it yields:

```
--- !map:HashWithIndifferentAccess 
"1092": ""
"869": ""
"1039": ""
"2492": ""
"1389": ""
"1200": ""
"600": ""
"1928": ""
"1767": ""
"1498": ""
"899": ""
"711": ""
"1124": ""
"1312": ""
"1500": ""
"900": ""
"1152": ""
"1232": ""
"1340": ""
"1420": ""
"123
```

Which is clearly not valid YAML, as it ends with a unterminated string.

Comment: It basically was truncated for some reason, probably ran out of the String length of 255, some other hashes in the table was saved and were able to be deserialized so I bet it's the length.