# rails console yaml parse error - applying solutions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**BACKGROUND** Complete newbie to coding working thro’ RailsTutorial on a windows 7 PC– I’ve stalled on chap 4.2 with an YAML error  running “rails console” from a command prompt with Ruby on Rails.

I need tips on how to interpret and use some specific answers (below)  that I found posted on stackoverflow/google groups/github.

I’ve tried to meet forum criteria for questions. If any of my confusions are too basic here  please let me know which & where else I might try.

The error -

~\Sites\sample_app rails console

```
C:/a_installers/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:154:in 'parse
    : (<unknown>): couldn't parse YAML at line 44 column 11 (Psych::SyntaxError)
            from C:/a_installers/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:
    54:in 'parse_stream'
```

(40 more lines like this)

Not sure what useful context I can supply.. possibly that I used Railsinstaller and  later Pik (instead of RVM) on Windows 7, that I installed ralis/ruby programs under  **c:\a_installers\railsInstaller** and that I’ve updated PATH to include ruby bin folders.

**QUESTION** The advice I'm having difficulty interpreting/using is..

1. [rails error, couldn't parse YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980877/rails-error-couldnt-parse-yaml) suggests

   a.  Run the YAML code through yamlint.com

   Which YAML file? All those in the error listing? I think I’m running rails console from my installed rails program area (above), there I found  60 odd files with “ *.yml “ – do I have to run all these through YAMLlint.com?

   b.  Manually Fix the YAML code

   One example given was   " fixing invalid yaml " involving splitting yaml code for a local date into lines.This was not applicable – I couldn’t find any such code in any of the 60 odd “ *.yml “ files under railsinstaller on my system

   c.  “load the old YAML parser (syck) with code xxx in config/boot.rb”

   Two problems…

   (1) I couldn’t find **boot.rb** in my the rails/ruby program area

   (2) I’m torn between two contrary views expressed

   “Psych is the new one, the one you should be using you have some invalid yaml somewhere.” 
   And

   “wrong… ruby should use a parser that is both maintained and supports existing usage, even if that usage is further from the spec. If only there were such a thing. Until there is, they should use syck..”

   In summary, not sure which files to amend, how to do that, how to check that. if it’s advisable instead to do a workaround  (reverting to syck) and if so in which directory and with which files.
2. another source rails-yaml-config-best-practice advised

   “configure parameter inside  environment.rb.” use a github code called “settings logic”

   Not sure how to do this..do I need to learn YAML? Tutorial hasn’t even started Ruby yet – is this
   Not sure where to do this – couldn’t find environment.rb in my rails/ruby program area – it seems to be part of my application (sample_app)

   In ..Settings_logic …the notes seem to bring me full circle to 1. above.

   “..Note: Certain Ruby/Bundler versions include a version of the Psych YAML parser which incorrectly handles merges (the `<<` in the example above.) If your default settings seem to be overwriting your environment-specific settings, including the following lines in your config/boot.rb file may solve the problem:

   require 'yaml'
   YAML::ENGINE.yamler= 'syck'

To apply this solution I still need to resolve question 1 c (2)

3  General advice - My inability to start rails console seems an absolute barrier for me to use ROR- a couple of general questions - Do practitioners use rails console for actual development or just learning? Can I learn RoR without rails console?

Many thanks for your patience, time and attention.