# Heroku syntax error; logs contain scrambled line numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, syntax-error

I've run into a strange bug in my Heroku-hosted Ruby on Rails 3.2.13 application that I can't replicate locally and I can't determine the cause.

Here are the symptoms:

On several pages I see the dreaded "We're sorry, but something went wrong" error:

[image]

The logs indicate there is a template error:

```
  Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 107.203.222.41 at 2013-05-27 13:45:18 +0000

  ActionView::Template::Error (syntax error on line 6, col 15: `'):
   15:   <%= f.password_field :password %></div>
   16: 
   21:   <div><%= f.submit "Sign in" %></div>
   19:   <% end -%>
   17:   <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
   18:     <div><%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label :remember_me %></div>
 app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_devise_sessions_new_html_erb__2053461519121638579_44147620'
 app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb:18:in `block in _app_views_devise_sessions_new_html_erb__2053461519121638579_44147620'
   20:
```

Notice how the line numbers are out of order.

Here's an example from another page:

```
  Started GET "/blog" for 107.203.222.41 at 2013-05-27 13:36:10 +0000

  ActionView::Template::Error (syntax error on line 6, col 15: `'):
  10:     <%= render :partial => "post", :collection => @posts %>
  13:   <% end %>

  9:   <%= content_tag(:div, :id => 'blog_content') do %>
  11: 
  12:     <%= will_paginate @posts, :page_links => false %>
  14: 
  15:   <%= render 'sidebar' %>
  app/views/posts/blog.html.erb:12:in `block (2 levels) in _app_views_posts_blog_html_erb___3437273290190956225_40741600'
  app/views/posts/blog.html.erb:9:in `block in _app_views_posts_blog_html_erb___3437273290190956225_40741600'
  app/views/posts/blog.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_posts_blog_html_erb___3437273290190956225_40741600'
```

Any idea what would cause this error? How can I identify exactly what "line 6, column 15" refers to?

Much appreciated!

**EDIT**

This makes no sense to me, but here's the line that's causing the issue:

```
 <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
   <div>
        <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
        <%#= f.label :remember_me %>
    </div>
 <% end -%>
```

If I comment out the f.label line, the page loads fine. If I uncomment it, I get that syntax error. What would cause this?

**EDIT 2**

I re-created the file from scratch and typed in the relevant portion of the code:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_url(resource_name), :autocomplete => 'off') do |f| %>
    <div>
         <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
         <%#= f.label :remember_me %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Same issue: When the f.label line is commented, the page loads. When it is uncommented, I get the same syntax error:

```
 ActionView::Template::Error (syntax error on line 6, col 15: `')
```

Comment: Normally the errors logs show the line numbers in order (10, 11, 12, 13...). Here the line numbers are not in order: (10, 13, 9, 11, 12, 14, 15).

Comment: Oh, of the extracted source, you mean, I thought you meant the stack trace.

Comment: Have you run all of the application's migrations on heroku?

Comment: My first guess would be a weird encoding on the source file and/or a corrupted Heroku slug.  Resave files in question locally, check them in, push to Heroku.  Or force a push of the current source to Heroku to make it rebuild the slug.  Yes...this is voodoo.

Comment: Silver: yep -- no migrations pending.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this was a problem with the YAML in en.yml.

Specifically, the YAML was originally:

```
# Sample localization file for English. Add more files in this directory for other locales.
# See https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/tree/master/rails%2Flocale for starting points.

en:
  activerecord:
    models:
    attributes:
```

If you plug this into something like http://yamllint.com/, you get the error message that I was seeing in the production logs:

```
syntax error on line 6, col 15: `'
```

Changing this back to the Rails default fixed the issue:

```
# Sample localization file for English. Add more files in this directory for other locales.
# See https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/tree/master/rails%2Flocale for starting points.

en:
  hello: "Hello world"
```

This thread has more information on YAML parsing in Rails that led me to identify the cause: [rails error, couldn't parse YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980877/rails-error-couldnt-parse-yaml)