# Rails error when Generate

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i started learning rails couple of days ago and i face errors every step 
i hardly get over the installation and when i came to this point of Generate Controller 
i got that error that i cant find any solution any ideas ?

```
> c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:148:in `parse': couldn't parse YAML
> at line 1 9 column 2 (Psych::SyntaxError)
```

> ScreenShot: http://sdrv.ms/12VD1Wu

Comment: Try: rails generate controller home index. I think you forgot to say that you want to generate a controller and an index view file.

Comment: i tried that and i got the same error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980877/rails-error-couldnt-parse-yaml, He got the  same error and solved check answer

Comment: i followed that post yesterday no any fix worked with me

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your `config/database.yml` file, in line 19, column 2. Fix the error and you will be able to proceed.

To get the file straight, you might want to google for "yml online validator" and use one of the suggested tools.

Comment: the error 10061 Error cannot connect to MySQL on Localhost but when i do mysql -u root -p i can connect