# Ruby on Rails No Method Error in Controller, trying to create a record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, methods, controller

I've got a ruby on rails application and am trying to save category data to the system, but whenever I click save I get the error:

```
NoMethodError in CategoriesController#create
undefined method `category' for #<Category id: nil, genre: "", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
Extracted source (around line #29):

27 def create
28 @category = Category.new(category_params)
29 if @category.save
30 redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was successfully created.'
31 else
32 render action: 'new'

Rails.root: C:/Sites/week_15/New/my_bookshop_test2 _basic
```

This is my code in the categories_controller.rb:

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_category, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
   def new
     @category = Category.new
   end
   def create
     @category = Category.new(category_params)
     if @category.save
       redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was successfully created.'
     else
       render action: 'new'
     end
   end
```

Can someone please help me.

Comment: show the full error stack

Comment: Post a full stacktrace, just like in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980877/rails-error-couldnt-parse-yaml

Comment: We need your category_params

Comment: # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def category_params
      params.require(:category).permit(:genre)
    end

Comment: can you also post code from your category model?

Comment: class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :products
 
 validates :category, :presence => { :message => "cannot be blank ..."}
  # display id and genre text e.g. 1 Detective, 2 Science Fiction, etc.
# used in category drop down selection box 
def category_info
 "#{id} #{genre}"
end
end

Comment: would be better to edit your question and add code formatted, but for me it seems that you are validating for presence of category in category itself. Should category belong to/have many other category / categories?

Comment: One category has many products, if that helps

Answer (score 0):

You should update the code from the comments in your question, because your model has a clear mistake in it:

Your code:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :products
  validates :category, :presence => { :message => "cannot be blank ..."} 
  # display id and genre text e.g. 1 Detective, 2 Science Fiction, etc. 
  # used in category drop down selection box    
  def category_info 
    "#{id} #{genre}"
  end 
end
```

If you take a look at the validation, you are trying to validate `category` itself instead of whatever it is you need to validate(from your previously posted code it looks like you need to validate `genre`)

For your code to work, you need to change it to this:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :products
  validates :genre, :presence => { :message => "cannot be blank ..."} 
  # display id and genre text e.g. 1 Detective, 2 Science Fiction, etc. 
  # used in category drop down selection box    
  def category_info 
    "#{id} #{genre}"
  end 
end
```

You use validations on attributes( like `genre` in your case), not the object itself.