# Translation Rails Tool

Tags: ruby-on-rails, translation, yaml

Here is my problem :

I'm working on a translation of webapp made with rails so i parse all of the missing translation and put it in my YML files but some of the translation have a "." at the end and it block my YML file to work.

It gives me this : "fr.admin.form.optional." so in my YML i should do this :

```
en:
 admin:
  form:
   optional.:
```

But obviously that's not working if anyone know how to deal with that without changing the source code of the app ...

Sorry for the long post, Sorry for the bad english Sorry for the lack of potatoes =)

Comment: can you try this advise ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5107098/2767755